# Is docker daemon of ipfs connecting to peers?

Tags: docker, go, ipfs, ipfs-cli, ipfs-http-client

Good day!

This is the situation.

We developed an application with IPFS using its container version on docker. But there is a suspicion that it does not connect to peers, because if you run the search locally, it will go through quickly.

So, are there any commands to add peers or do I need to add bootstraps??

Comment: Have you tried this command for listing which peers you are connected to? https://flyingzumwalt.gitbooks.io/ipfs-primer/content/going-online/lessons/find-peers.html

Comment: That seems easy to test; just try fetching an ipfs resource that's not available locally.

Comment: @larsks Yeah, while testing non-locally resource, we get timeout after 2 hours

Comment: Are the ports currently exposed in the dockerfile / compose?